# Java/JNA Looking to create pointer for a byte array to pass to a native method expecting a LPSTR argument

Tags: java, jna

I want to pass a Pointer to a byte[]  array, to a native 
routine. I do not have any capability to modify the the native code. I can merely utilize it.

The method expects an image, in an LPSTR data type. I've looked at other C code that consumes the native routine.
They appear to be passing in an array of bytes.

So, my process is to obtain a buffered image object, get the corresponding byte array for the image, and attempt to pass that to the native routine.
I've tried to pass the array directly, I've tried to write the array to Memory, and I've tried to pass a bytebuffer as well. I still keep getting an 'Invalid memory access' exception.

Using the Memory Class:

```
byte[] imageBytes = getImageBytes(image);
Pointer imagePointer = new Memory(imageBytes.length);
imagePointer.write(0, imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
nativeInterface.SendImageData(port, imagePointer, x, y, w, h);
```

Using the ByteBuffer:

```
ByteBuffer bBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(imageBytes.length);
bBuffer.put(imageBytes);
Pointer imagePointer = Native.getDirectBufferPointer(bBuffer);
return cspStatInterface.SendImageData(port, imagePointer, x, y, w, h);
```

Passing Byte Array Directly:

```
byte[] imageBytes = getImageBytes(image);
nativeInterface.SendImageData(port, imageBytes, x, y, w, h);
```

I've been looking everywhere, and I can't seem to find a solution. I've verified, that the byte array is filled with appropriate data as well. Am I not properly constructing the Pointer? Is there a better way to create the pointer?

Comment: If it's an LPSTR, is anything expecting a null character at the end, in the receiving code or code that it calls?

Comment: Please include your native declaration.  What size pixel is the native code expecting?  Typically 8 bits is not sufficient storage for an image pixel.

Comment: I believe you all are correct. Upon re-sizing the memory object (w x h x 4) I was able to successfully complete the call to the native function. The native call actually takes the data and prints an image, from the supplied data.
Currently, the image that gets printed appears to be a garbled mess. So, I must be supplying pixel data inappropriately to the native method, but that is a different issue.

By the way, the native function declaration is:
long SendImagedata(long portNum, LPSTR buffer, long XPos, long YPos, long width, long height)
(buffer: the data is a RGB 24bit color data)

Comment: Adding response by a jna project member: "What is your native function declaration?  If your native code is truly expecting a buffer, then passing `byte[]` should work, but you need to ensure that it’s of sufficient size. 

Most likely your native code is expecting your individual pixels to be of a size larger than a byte, and runs off the end of allocated memory. 

Try passing in a Memory object of size w X h X 4, and zero its contents, or pass in an `int[]` of size w X h. 

Alternatively you can set w = h = 1 and x = y = 0, which ensures the native code will only read one “pixel”. "